# MVC Razor code fail to run in MVC3 but work perfectly in MVC 4 ?. Why this happen to this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc3 apps that initially made in MVC3. From that time it's work fine. Recently we make a new section (directory as MVC3 apps).

I tried to run same code in MVC3.it's failed to run but fine in MVC4. Here is the problematic code.

```
 <ul>
                        @{
                            foreach (TestManager.TestSummary latest in latests.GetRange(0, 3))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <div class="short">
                                        <div class="short_holder">
                                            @if (latest.HasThumbnail == PostManager.ImageStatus.HasImage)
                                            {
                                                <a href="@(latest.URL)" title="@(latest.Title)">
                                                    <img class="image" width="128px" height="80px" style="overflow:hidden;" alt="@(latest.Title)" src="@(Globals.POST_THUMBNAIL_PATH + "/" + latest.ID + ".png")" />
                                                </a>
                                            }
                                            <h3>
                                                <a href="@(latest.URL)" title="@(latest.Title)" class="hoveranchor">
                                                    @(latest.Title.BlahBlah(50))
                                                </a>
                                            </h3>
                                            @(latest.Excerpt.BlahBlah(105))...
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            }

                        }
                    </ul>
```

This code run fine in MVC4 apps but It's show me some issue. Another page I have made work fine on my PC but it's never load fully when I tried to fetch it from server. that page is still load.

one page's code I show you here. If you check then it's look clearly validated. I run it and it's work only in MVC4. MVC3 (where we need to deploy) doesn't take our code to work.

From some SO/Forum post it's look MVC3 and MVC3 update is 2 different version. Is that kind of thing have something means to this post.

My main purpose to make this thread to figure out why this code work in MVC4 but not in MVC3.

The given code gave me this error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ';'
Line 54:                                 <li>
Line 55:                                     <div class="short">
Line 56:                                         <div class="short_holder">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with evolution of Razor engine. I've noticed a similar problem in going from MVC4 to MVC5.

For example, 
In MVC4 in your View you could say the following

```
@using My.Namespace
```

but in MVC5 you'd get an error because you must have a semicolon at the end

```
@using My.Namespace;
```

It seems that each new version of Razor "approaches" C# style.

So in your situation I believe you have a `;` floating somewhere in your Razor block (maybe just above the code you posted?).

Comment: Thanks for your help,BTW I am not using MVC5, I use MVC3 and MVC3 on server. The way my code work on my PC doesn't make work on server ?. Do I missing something ?

Comment: Based on the error first thing that came to mind is you changed your MVC3 code so that it only works in MVC4. The change could be that you added a semicolon at the end of a line (at least that's what the error message is alluding to). That's what I meant by differences in Razor versions..